# Column total does not match values in rows

Tags: powerbi

The table I'm trying to create is quite simple. It's containers sold * Deposits, containers sold * Pickups, and containers sold * Sorting and Processing.

The correct values show while the column total is way off. What is causing this?

The formula for Deposits, Pickups, and Sorting and Processing is

```
= SUM( Summary[Deposits] ) * [Containers Sold]
```

[image]

Comment: Update the question to include the expression for `[Containers Sold]`